# How to interpret this jade code into HTML?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm learning jade and following a tutorial on user account creation.

I was using a jade to HTML converter, but the program can't seem to figure out this bit of code:

```
 #user
                h1.text-center.login-title Welcome #{user.firstName}. Check your details below:
                    div.signup-wall
                        ul.user-details
                            li Username ---> #{user.username}
                            li Email    ---> #{user.email}
                            li First Name ---> #{user.firstName} 
                            li Last Name ---> #{user.lastName}
```

Specifically, the #{user.firstName} part is confusing. What does it mean, and how would one translate that into HTML?

Answer (score 1):

It's a templating engine variable, it's supposed to be injected while rendering jade to html, usually done by server like this:

```
app.render('login.jade', {
    user: {
        username: 'xyz'
    }
})
```

If you're trying to convert something like this (login.jade) to pure html  (login.html) chances are this probably can't be translated because pure HTML isn't dynamic to inject values, or you'll have to manually write what `user.username` was supposed to be.

```
<li> xyz </li>
```

More info for jade: http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**,

Consider the following steps :

1. Go to [html2jade.org](http://html2jade.org/)
2. Copy your JADE template code there over given space

And

**And you will get your Jade code equivalent  in HTML**

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was using, but it doesn't work. The website isn't able to translate it. So I'm wondering whether or not the tutorial I got this code from is wrong in some way.